# For which value of m are these 3 vectors linearly dependent?

Tags: matrices, vectors

In one of my revision worksheets there is a question which goes as follows:

The vectors u=*m*i+j+k, v=i+*m*j+k and w=i+j+*m*k, where *m* is a real constant, are linearly dependent for either m=0, m=1, m=2, m=3 or m=4.

I configured the vectors into a 3x3 matrix, took the determinant and set it equal to 0 and then solved for *m* and I ended up with m=-2 or 1. As m=-2 was not an option and m=1 would make all of the vectors parallel and hence linearly independent (I think?), where am I going wrong?

Alternately, is there a better way of approaching this question that does not involve matrices?

Comment: parallel vectors are linearly dependent....( in this case, 1u-1v=0)

Comment: I thought that this was only true in two dimensions? My textbook only talks about coplanar, non-parallel vectors in 3 dimensions as being linearly dependent. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of putting the vectors into a matrix, taking the determinant, and setting it equal to 0, and solving for m is correct. However, the key insight into why this method is correct is the fact that the determinant of a matrix is 0 if and only if the rows are linearly dependent.

So because you set the determinant equal to 0, you know that values of m that you found makes vectors linearly dependent.